# htaccess rewrite folder to folder/filename wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a wordpress website in /subfolder.

In the root, there is a folder called /reports/

I need to rewrite url so /reports/ becomes /reports/index.php but wordpress is changing path to be /reports/. (and I get page not found)

This is my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /


# Only apply to URLs that aren't already under /wordpress2.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wordpress2/

# Rewrite all those to insert /wordpress2.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wordpress2/$1

# Redirect the root folder.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?website.com.au$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ wordpress2/ [L]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^/reports$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /reports/index.php/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^freeloancalculator.com.au/reports$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.reeloancalculator\.com\.au/reports$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/reeloancalculator\.com\.au/reports/index.php\/" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks! Please could you change the website address to be: website.com.au instead? I will try your code now.. thank you

Answer (score 0):

I hadn't tried this, but I think this will help you..

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/index.php /reports=$1/ [NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

By adding ./ /index.php, it fixes the issue

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ./ /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```